# Нужен ли знак препинания в этом предложении?

Tags: запятые

Нужно ли ставить запятую после слова "фильмы"? *Выберите **фильмы**, на которые вы хотите сходить.*

Comment: (**вы**) *выберете* фильмы - повелительное наклонение, главное; на которые **вы** *хотите сходить* - придаточное. Сложноподчиненное, который/на которые - союз, две пары основ, запятая нужна, всё верно.

Comment: Зато, думаю, не всё верно в вашем комментарии. Повелительное наклонение от глагола "выбрать" — *вы́бер**и**те* (*выберете* — будущее время), *на которые* — союзное слово.

Answer (score 2):

*Выберите фильмы* [какие?], ***на которые** вы хотите сходить.*

Запятая ставится в сложноподчиненном предложении (СПП) с придаточным определительным перед союзным словом "**на которые**".